# Delphi XE3: Webbrowser: Populating a setattribute with text works, but using a variable doesn't

Tags: delphi

I got this code from another post on here, works fine...

```
WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID('name').setAttribute('value', '123456');
```

However, if I put a string variable in place of '123456' I get a "Bad Variable Type" error.

```
var 
  somevar:string; 
begin  
somevar:='123456';
WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID('name').setAttribute('value', somevar);
end;
```

What am I doing wrong?  Many thanks!

(Edited to show somevar declaration and usage);

Comment: Probably `somevar` is not a string or any kind of variable type supported by `setAttribute`. Please share the part where you defined/set `somevar`

Comment: The website I'm posting to (behind a login, unfortunately), is expecting a numeric invoice no.  123456 works fine when hard-wired into the setattribute call, but if I use a variable instead I get the error.

Comment: You are interacting with a COM object, so use `WideString` instead of `string`. `WideString` is a wrapper for COM's `BSTR` string type.

Comment: Thank you Remy for that tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cured!  setattribute is thinking that the all-numeric string variable I'm using should be converted into a numeric, which is not acceptable to the webpage.  Concatenating the variable with a null string within the setattribute call prevents this behaviour.

```
var 
  somevar:string; 
begin  
somevar:='123456';
WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID('name').setAttribute('value', ''+somevar);
end;
```